# Считывание слов из файла в C

Tags: c

как считывать слова из файла так, чтобы каждое новое слово перезаписывалось в одну и ту же переменную, но для переменной каждый раз должен выполняться malloc учитывая размер считываемого слова. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы в программе появилось столько переменных, сколько слов находиться в файле?

Comment: или использовать массив.

Comment: нет я хочу чтобы был какой-то цикл считывания каждого слова отдельно и на каждой итерации в одну переменную перезаписывалось новое слово с выделением памяти для каждого солва динамически

Comment: если максимальная длина слова известна, то можно выделит сразу памяти и использовать fgets. Если же длина слова может быть ну совсем разной, тогда придется делать чтение по частям и выделять аккуратно память

Comment: В linux (вообще, в GNU) можно использовать формат `%ms` для динамического выделения памяти при чтении слова -- `char *w; fscanf(in_file,  "%ms",  &w)`.

Comment: А какой в этом смысл? Это же потеря эффективности (выделение памяти — задача длительная).

Comment: Просто лучше тогда сразу создать переменную на ограниченное количество памяти?

Comment: @Harry, выделений будет мало если не сокращать ранее выделенную память. Я считаю что задача чтения произвольных строк в C нигде нормально не описана. Я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @loaf4 - "цикл считывания каждого слова отдельно" - В стандартной библиотеке С нет функции чтения **слова**. Есть функции чтения символа и чтения строки. Или Вы предполагаете, что каждое слово - на отдельной строке?

Comment: @Sergey, `scanf("%s", ...)` читает "a sequence of non-whitespace characters (a string)". Специальной функции нет, способ читать слова есть.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy - "способ читать слова есть" - Неужели Вы думаете, что я этого не знал?!  Вопрос только в том, что такое **слово** и всегда ли они *non-whitespace*. А слова, перечисленные через запятую - это одно слово? Я поэтому и попросил уточнить, как TS собирается читать **слова**.

Answer (score 1):

Коротко не получилось. Основная идея - нужна структура, которая будет хранить считанное слово и умеет распределять память из кучи при необходимости.

Если памяти не хватает, выделяется новый буфер в два раза большего размера. Это гарантирует что память будет редко выделятся и общая сложность останется линейной (от числа прочитанных символов). Если следующее слово короче, память назад не возвращается.

`CharArray` - структура для хранения слова. Нотация `= {0}` означает "обнулить все поля". Обнулить необходимо, иначе будет неопределённое поведение.

`CharArray_read_word` читает слово из потока и возвращает успех если удалось прочесть что-то и памяти хватило. Неуспех означает, что нет памяти чтобы вместить слово или не прочитано ни одного символа. Даже есть памяти не хватило, структура остаётся в согласованном состоянии и нет никаких утечек. Если всё прошло успешно, данные в буфере дополняются нулевым символом. Получается строка в стиле `C`.

`CharArray_clear` опустошает структуру, возвращая всю выделенную память. Структурой можно пользоваться дальше.

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "char_array.h"

int main() {
    CharArray a = {0};

    while (CharArray_read_word(&a, stdin)) {
        puts(a.data);
    }
    CharArray_clear(&a);
}
```

Структура хранит `capacity` - размер буфера, `size` - сколько места в буфере занято под данные, `data` - сам буфер. Даже если `CharArray_read_word` вернула неуспех, в буфер можно заглянуть: первые `size` байт будут хранить прочитанные символы.

```
// char_array.h
#ifndef CHAR_ARRAY_H_
#define CHAR_ARRAY_H_

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct CharArray {
    int capacity;
    int size;
    char *data;
} CharArray;

void CharArray_clear(CharArray *a);
bool CharArray_read_word(CharArray *a, FILE *f);

#endif // CHAR_ARRAY_H_
```

Реализация длинная, к сожалению. `skip_spaces` пропускает пробельные символы (обратите внимание на `ungetc`). `append_char` добавляет символ в буфер. Если буфер недостаточно велик, он "растягивается" вызовом `realloc`. `read_word` читает непробельные символы и помещает их в буфер.

`CharArray_clear` освобождает память и возвращает буфер в исходное состояние. `CharArray_read_word` пропускает пробелы и читает слово. Прочитанные данные дополняются нулевым символом.

```
// char_array.c
#include "char_array.h"

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static bool skip_spaces(FILE *f) {
    int c;
    for (; ; ) {
        c = getc(f);
        if (c == EOF) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!isspace(c)) {
            ungetc(c, f);
            return true;
        }
    }
}

static bool append_char(CharArray *a, char c) {
    if (a->size >= a->capacity) {
        int capacity = (a->capacity <= 0) ? 16 : 2 * a->capacity;
        char *data = realloc(a->data, capacity);
        if (data == NULL) {
            return false;
        }
        a->capacity = capacity;
        a->data = data;
    }
    a->data[a->size++] = c;
    return true;
}

static bool read_word(CharArray *a, FILE *f) {
    a->size = 0;
    int c;
    for (; ; ) {
        c = getc(f);
        if (c == EOF) {
            return true;
        }
        if (isspace(c)) {
            ungetc(c, f);
            return true;
        }
        if (!append_char(a, c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

void CharArray_clear(CharArray *a) {
    free(a->data);
    a->capacity = 0;
    a->size = 0;
    a->data = NULL;
}

bool CharArray_read_word(CharArray *a, FILE *f) {
    if (!skip_spaces(f)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!read_word(a, f)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (a->size <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return append_char(a, '\0');
}
```

Сборка и тестирование:

> ```
>  $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I. main.c char_array.c
>  $ ./a.out < main.c
> #include
> <stdio.h>
> #include
> "char_array.h"
> int
> main()
> {
> CharArray
> a
> =
> {0};
> while
> (CharArray_read_word(&a,
> stdin))
> {
> puts(a.data);
> }
> CharArray_clear(&a);
> }
> ```

Реализация написана так чтобы получилось минимальное количество кода. Что можно изменить в реальной программе?

Нет защиты от переполнения. Если `int` - 32 бита, то слово из 2GB символов сломает программу. Как минимум надо написать защиту. Возможно перейти на беззнаковые типы. Возможно перейти на 64 бита (`long long`) для `capacity` и `size`.

Добавить `bool CharArray_reserve(CharArray *a, int capacity);` чтобы у программиста была возможность выделить заранее буфер разумного размера и избежать выделения памяти при чтении нормального файла с нормальными словами.

Добавить `bool CharArray_shrink(CharArray *a);` чтобы освободить память выделенную про запас, оставив лишь объём необходимый для текущей строки.

Изменить реализацию так чтобы всегда оставалось место под нулевой символ в конце строки. Сейчас он добавляется как обычный символ, что может привести к нехватке памяти в самом конце.

**P.S.** Не могу похвастать большим опытом работы именно с `C`. Если вы видите ошибку или плохой стиль, оставьте комментарий. Поправим.

**P.P.S.** Глядя на объём кода нужный для решения рутинной задачи можно понять зачем был придуман `C++` и `STL`. :)

Comment: Вот [пример](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/getdelim.c) аналогичной функции [getdelim](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (ну, да, она не пропускает разделители, но это мелкая деталь), реализованной на знании внутреннего устройства FILE. Можете подправить свою (хотя бы в том же стиле передачи параметров)

Comment: @avp, это сложнее чем допустимо в прикладном программировании (как мне кажется). Я попытался сделать пример как можно более простым (и в реализации и в использовании).

Comment: Дело вкуса -). / Кстати, если использовать [malloc_usable_size](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html), то можно не хранить capacity (тогда usable (?) прототип может быть таким -- `ssize_t getword(char **word, const char word_delims[], FILE *stream);`)

Comment: @avp, это уже приемлемо. Но это не стандартный С. :(

Comment: А кто-то считает, что GNU это стандарт де-факто и плевать хотел на другие мнения. Это из серии -- "вам шашечки или ехать?"